# Transform dynamic XML to CSV/Text

Tags: xml, powershell, export-to-csv

I have an XML file that has various elements & attributes.  Some will be common to all, but not every node will have all (or the same) ones.  Sample XML is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<index>
    <doc id='0'>
        <field name='IDTREE' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>-</val>
        </field>
        <field name='role' norm='114' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>administrators</val>
        </field>
        <field name='internalid' norm='117' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>123456</val>
        </field>
        <field name='version' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>test</val>
        </field>
        <field name='id' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>myname-123456-test</val>
        </field>
        <field name='siteId' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>myname</val>
        </field>
    </doc>
    <doc id='1'>
        <field name='internalid' norm='117' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>98765</val>
        </field>
        <field name='version' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>dev</val>
        </field>
        <field name='category' norm='113' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>biography</val>
        </field>
        <field name='display' norm='120' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>false</val>
        </field>
        <field name='publisher' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>-</val>
        </field>
        <field name='id' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>myname-98765-dev</val>
        </field>
        <field name='siteId' norm='124' flags='Idfp--S--Ni08--------'>
            <val>myname</val>
        </field>
    </doc>
</index>
```

What I want to do is to transform this (very large) XML file into a text file (pipe delimited) that I can import into Excel (or SQL). I would want the output to be like:

```
id|siteId|version|internalid|role|IDTREE|category|display|publisher
myname-123456-test|myname|test|123456|administrators|-|||
myname-98765-dev|myname|dev|98765|||biography|false|-
```

I think I would need to make 2 passes on the XML data, the first one to get the column names, and the second to add the data into the appropriate field to be output to the text file.

I know that each doc will have at least 4 of the same field nodes:  id, siteId, version and internalid.  Everything else can vary.

My initial thought was to make 1 pass through the XML, adding the name attributes of the field to a hash table.  On pass 2, I would use the hash table to loop through & assign each of the fields in its appropriate place on the output.

I'm using this now to read the XML file.

```bsh
$f = [System.Xml.XmlReader]::Create("C:\Test\MyXMLFile.xml")

while ($f.read()) {
    switch ($f.NodeType) {
        ([System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element) {
            if ($f.Name -eq "doc") {
                $e = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($f)               
                $nbr = [String] $e.Attribute("id").Value
                $fields = $e.Descendants("field")
                foreach ($fld in $fields) {
                    $z = $fld.FirstAttribute.Value
                    $z1 = $fld.Element("val").Value
                }
                # write output 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this than how I am considering?

Comment: That depends on what "better" means to you

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - unfortunately, "better" doesn't always mean what it says.  I'd hope that in this case, "better" would mean easier.  But in the real world, "better" often means the option that stinks the least.  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've pointed out yourself, and as [Ansgar has already shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37009376/712649), the best procedure here is to:

1. Iterate through the file once to find all possible column names
2. Iterate through the file again and create structured objects based on 1

That being said, if you're working with HUGE xml files, your approach with an XmlReader is probably faster and less memory intensive than parsing the entire file.

I would simplify your current code, and split it off into two similar but distinct operations.

Let's start with step 1, gathering the field names:

```
# Import the XElement-to-XML linq assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Xml.Linq |Out-Null

function Get-FieldNames
{
    param(
        [string]$Path = "C:\Test\MyXMLFile.xml",
        [switch]$AsHashTable
    )

    # Create reader
    $xmlReader = [System.Xml.xmlReader]::Create($Path)

    # Set up a dictionary
    $hashTable = [ordered]@{}

    # Read through the file
    while ($xmlReader.Read()) 
    {
        # Only interested in the <doc> elements
        if($xmlReader.NodeType -eq [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element -and $xmlReader.Name -eq "doc") 
        {
            $docElement = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($xmlReader)
            foreach ($field in $docElement.Descendants("field")) 
            {
                # Grab name of each field entry and set dictionary entry
                $fieldName = $field.Attribute("name").Value
                $hashTable[$fieldName] = $null
            }
        }
    }

    if($AsHashTable)
    {
        return $hashTable
    }
    else
    {
        return $hashTable.Keys
    }
}
```

Now we can use the first function to create a template for a property table that we can later use with `New-Object -Property`:

```
$objectTemplate = Get-FieldNames -AsHashTable
```

Great! All set to parse the actual values. Pretty much same strategy as before:

```
function Get-XMLFieldValues 
{
    param(
        [string]$Path = "C:\dev\test\huge.xml",
        [hashtable]$Template
    )

    # Create reader
    $xmlReader = [System.Xml.xmlReader]::Create($Path)

    # Read through the file
    while ($xmlReader.Read()) 
    {
        # Only interested in the <doc> elements
        if($xmlReader.NodeType -eq [System.Xml.XmlNodeType]::Element -and $xmlReader.Name -eq "doc") 
        {
            $docElement = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::ReadFrom($xmlReader)

            # This is important - clone the template HashTable, don't reuse it
            $objectProperties = $Template.Clone()

            foreach ($field in $docElement.Descendants("field")) 
            {
                # Grab name of the current field entry
                $fieldName = $field.Attribute("name").Value
                # Assign the value from the <val> child node
                $objectProperties[$fieldName] = $($field.Descendants("val")|Select-Object -First 1).Value
            }
            # Create and emit a psobject
            New-Object psobject -Property $objectProperties
        }
    }
}
```

Combine it with the hashtable from step 1, et voila:

```
Get-XMLFieldValues -Template $objectTemplate |ft -AutoSize
```

[image: Ready to Export!]

Now all you need to do is pipe the output to `Export-Csv -Delimite '|'` instead for `Format-Table`

Comment: this works perfectly!  Thank you for the functions.  And for the laugh also.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Test\MyXMLFile.xml'

# transform XML to list of custom objects
$docs = $xml.SelectNodes('//doc') | ForEach-Object {
    $props = @{}
    $_.Field | ForEach-Object { $props[$_.name] = $_.val }
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $props
}

# get list of unique property names
$props = $docs | ForEach-Object {
    Get-Member -InputObject $_ -Type NoteProperty
} | Select-Object -Expand Name -Unique

# add missing properties to objects
$docs | ForEach-Object {
    $doc = $_
    $props | Where-Object {
        $_.PSObject.Properties.Name -notcontains $_
    } | ForEach-Object {
        $doc | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $_ -Value ''
    }
}

# export object list to CSV
$docs | Export-Csv 'C:\Test\MyXMLFile.csv' -Delimiter '|' -NoType
```

Comment: With a `-Delimiter "|"` switch on the last line?